# How to build DockPanel with transparent background using c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm writting an app that use `DevExpress` winforms user controls in it.

In my app, it contains left and right dockpanel. it shows the panel control containing a dock manager whenever a dock panel is set to `AutoHide`.
But, I need to set the dock panel's background to transparent background or color background.
It looks like web page control.

Who can help me to make my control pretty?

Best regards.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what are you trying to achieve. Can you clarify your question? Add an image or two, maybe?